# Looking for an escrow-type service that enables me to give the contributor more money back than they originally put in

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

Does anyone know of a payment-processing service (2checkout.com, braintree.com or something like a transpact.com) or indeed a method that will allow you to refund the customer's payment, and also pay them back extra, to their CC or paypal account? "Refund" could be a confusing word here, so let me explain:

They pay €10 by CC, you pay them back €16.66.

So it would be an escrow-type system. Say 10 users set a goal for themselves (there will be a few goals to choose from), and put €10 each into the escrow (pay with CC or paypal).

Now there is €100 in the escrow.

4 users do not complete the goal, so they forfeit their contribution. This leaves the €100 to be divided among the 6.

The remaining 6 users will now receive €16.66 each.

Is there a way of paying each individual user who completed the goal their initial sum + the remainder of the escrow / by no. of users left?

Is their a service that will let you 'compensate' customers for instance?

Many thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a [non-referenced credit](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_NVP/), which allows you to push funds to a credit cards without refunding an original transaction, and you can set the amount to whatever you need.

If everybody has PayPal accounts you could just use the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) to send money to each one accordingly.

If you're working with PHP my [class library](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) will make this very simple for you.